# Making use of pre-stringified JSON pieces

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I already have a JSON string; perhaps I got it from the server.

```
data = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```

I want to use `postMessage` or some other API which requires a JSON string and send it the information in the form

```
{ action: 'save', data }
```

Of course I could do

```
postMessage(JSON.stringify({ action: 'save', data: JSON.parse(data) });
```

but this ends up arsing the data and then immediately restringifying it as part of the stringified object being send to `postMessage`.

Is there any clean way to take advantage of the fact that I already have the stringified version of part of the data to be sent? I am concerned about this because actually data could be 100K or more in length and parsing it and stringifying it is not free.

Note: I know I could send the JSON string for data as is and have the receiving side parse it, but I cannot change the semantics of the receiving side.

Note 2: Of course I could also engage in various ways of building the JSON myself, such as

```
'{ "action": "save", "data": ' + data + '}'
```

but would prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var data = {
    "a":"test1",
    "b":"test2",
    "c":{
        "c1":"test3.1",
        "c2":"test3.2"
    }
}

var object = {};

object["action"] = "save";
object["data"] = data;

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same question and was pointed to here. 
There are different solutions to this. I setup a little [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/prestringifyed-json/2) test.

Most promising aproach (if you don't need to have the thing nested) is removing the end and adding the stringified json:

```
var stringifiedObject = JSON.stringify({
  some: 'random',
  obj: 'propterties'
});
var res = JSON.stringify({
 outer: 'object'
});
res = res.substring(0, res.length-1) + ', "alreadyString":' + stringifiedObject + '}';
```